# Read from internal storage file (Android)

Tags: android

How to read the particular data from the internal storage file.
For eg., I have stored 
1. Device    2. Time(epoch format)     3. button text

```
            CharSequence cs =((Button) v).getText();
            t = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    s = cs.toString();
    buf = (t+"\n").getBytes();
    buf1 = (s+"\n").getBytes();


    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(Filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        fos.write("DVD".getBytes());
        fos.write(tab.getBytes());
        fos.write(buf);
        fos.write(tab.getBytes());
        fos.write(buf1);
        //fos.write(tab.getBytes());
        //fos.write((R.id.bSix+"\n").getBytes());
        fos.write(newline.getBytes());
        //fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

then while reading, how can we read only price from the file? (using fos.read())

Thanks

Comment: Please add some more details. How have you "stored" Device, Time and Price? Show some code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing the file in a more structured way, like this:

```
long t = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
String s = ((Button) v).getText();
DataOutputStream dos = null;
try {
    dos = new DataOutputStream(openFileOutput(Filename, Context.MODE_APPEND));
    dos.writeUTF("DVD");
    dos.writeLong(t); // Write time
    dos.writeUTF(s); // Write button text
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (dos != null) {
        try {
            dos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
}
```

To read it back, something like this:

```
DataInputStream dis = null;
try {
    dis = new DataInputStream(openFileInput(Filename));
    String dvd = dis.readUTF();
    long time = dis.readLong();
    String buttonText = dis.readUTF();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (dis != null) {
        try {
            dis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
}
```